# Unable to save my activity state even after implementing onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onsaveinstancestate

I am setting up an app in which I am adding a card layout. On clicking the add button a card is added with user name and details. On clicking the card a new activity opens. Everything works fine except when I close the activity all the added cards vanishes and the app starts completely blank new. 
    Also on changing app orientation after adding cards app crashes giving leaked window exception. Kinsly help me with a solution

I had overridden the onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods as visible at the end of the code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    mcontext=this;

    buttonScan = findViewById(R.id.fab);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    dialog1 = new Dialog(Activity.this);
    context = getApplicationContext();

   /* SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean shouldDisplayCard = sharedPref.getBoolean("should_display_card", false);

    if(shouldDisplayCard)
        cardview();*/

    buttonScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addhome();
            /* scanWifi();
            dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
            dialog1.setTitle("Scanning");
            listView = dialog1.findViewById(R.id.wifiList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            dialog1.show();*/
        }
    });

    homeLayout = findViewById(R.id.homelayout);

    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    tv.setText("Currently no device is added, Tap '+' to add a new device.");
    tv.setTextSize(21);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setPadding(70, 470, 70, 50);
    homeLayout.addView(tv);

}

public void addhome() {
    dialog2 = new Dialog(Activity.this);
    dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.add_home);
    v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.add_home, null);
    dialog2.setContentView(v);
    dialog2.show();

    editText1 = v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    passtext1 = v.findViewById(R.id.passText1);
    passtext2 = v.findViewById(R.id.passText2);

    homebut = v.findViewById(R.id.homeBut);

    homebut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (editText1.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please input Home name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if (passtext1.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0 || passtext2.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if (!passtext1.getText().toString().trim().equals(passtext2.getText().toString().trim()))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords do not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                pass1 = passtext1.getText().toString().trim();
                pass2 = passtext2.getText().toString().trim();
                cardview();
                /*SharedPreferences sharedPref = mcontext.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("should_display_card", true);
                editor.apply();*/
                dialog2.hide();
                homeLayout.removeView(tv);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void cardview() {

    cardview = new CardView(context);
    layoutparams1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutparams1.setMargins(18, 30, 18, 0);
    cardview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams1);
    cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    cardview.setMinimumHeight(400);
    cardview.setRadius(30);

    textview1 = new TextView(context);
    //textview1.setLayoutParams(layoutparams1);
    textview1.setText(editText1.getText().toString().trim());
    textview1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 28);
    textview1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textview1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    textview1.setPadding(30, 35, 25, 65);
    textview1.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    textview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
            Activity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    textview2 = new TextView(context);
   // textview2.setLayoutParams(layoutparams1);
    textview2.setText("Connection: ");
    textview2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
    textview2.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    textview2.setPadding(30, 165, 25, 45);
    textview2.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

    textview3 = new TextView(context);
   // textview3.setLayoutParams(layoutparams1);
    textview3.setText("Security: ");
    textview3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
    textview3.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    textview3.setPadding(30, 255, 25, 45);
    textview3.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

    textview4 = new TextView(context);
    //textview4.setLayoutParams(layoutparams1);
    textview4.setText("Active");
    textview4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    textview4.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
    textview4.setPadding(450,  165, 25, 45);
    textview4.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

    textview5 = new TextView(context);
    textview5.setLayoutParams(layoutparams1);
    textview5.setText("Inactive");
    textview5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    textview5.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
    textview5.setPadding(450, 215, 25, 45);
    textview5.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

    cardview.addView(textview1);
    cardview.addView(textview2);
    cardview.addView(textview3);
    cardview.addView(textview4);
    cardview.addView(textview5);

    homeLayout.addView(cardview);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    final EditText textBox = v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    CharSequence userText = textBox.getText();
    outState.putCharSequence("savedText", userText);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
    final EditText textBox = v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    CharSequence userText = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("savedText");
    textBox.setText(userText);
}
```

Comment: For that, you have to store the changes to the database.
If you want to store the data locally on the mobile then go for the SQLite and
if you want to store the data globally then go for mysql, mongodb, or firebase.

Comment: But for multiple answers I have gone through it seems that this can be achieved by overriding onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to store them locally on database.
try [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

Comment: But after going through multiple solutions it seems that this can be achieved by overriding onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods

Comment: onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() are there to preserve activity when it is destroyed and recreated (Like when you rotate device) when you shut down your app all memory is lost

Comment: Whenever an app shuts the means the activity is destroyed. Kindly refer to the official android documentation which states that:  savedInstanceState Bundle: If the activity is being re-initialized after previously being shut down then this Bundle contains the data it most recently supplied in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Note: Otherwise it is null. This value may be null.

Comment: @HoshangS saveinstancestate is only used to restore the state of activity (thinkgs like checked checkboxes, text in edittexts etc.). If you close your app the activity is considered finished and it's state will NOT be reinitialized.

Comment: Thanks although for app restart case I'll consider using a database but even during orientation change, the app is crashing with a leaked window exception.

Comment: Any idea as to how can I use sharedpreferences here to retain my card layout state?